# Div stay visible on click focus

Tags: html, css, textbox, focus, tabindex

I have tried alot but dont know how to do it.

Im trying to do box sliding out from the site like the one on facebook but in 100% css and html. I can make it with the hover but the way i am looking for is the click and if you click outsite the box it would slide back in again

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking on the textbox sets the focus there, so it won't be on the `span` next to it. Change your CSS so that the textbox is visible when focus is there as well.

```
span:focus ~ .to-be-changed, .to-be-changed:focus {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Think i got it now